# running eclipse debugger with program launched by script

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

How do you run the debugger in Eclipse on a program launched with a Python script?

I have a executable (written in Fortran) that is launched using Python and I would like to use gdb integrated in Eclipse, but I don't know how to tell Eclipse or GDB what executable I am trying to debug.

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Indigo Service Release 2 on Mac OSX Lion.